# CSS selectors grouping: element.class element element.class element - what does it selects?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a CSS provided which contains following code

```
table.exm_table tbody tr.odd td{
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
```

I'm not sure what should it style. Will be background color set at the td element in following structure?

```
<table class="exm_table">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>Is this an selected element?</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

EDIT:

Actually I've overlooked second part of the CSS:

```
table.exm_table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td,
table.exm_table tbody tr.odd td
```

Which caused my confusion why code haven't been working...

Comment: Yes..Next question! Except that this `<td class="odd">` should be this `<tr class="odd">`

Comment: What's the point asking this kind of question and don't just try it by yourself?

Comment: Paulie_D - my fault. I've just updated it.

Comment: user3560463 - actually when I published a question I had the same feeling but it was too late. But maybe someone will find it useful somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML <strike>is</strike> was incorrect but otherwise the CSS will work and targets the `td`. Note that in your (original) example there is no table-row `<tr>`. You'll see it works with the corrected mark-up:

```
<table class="exm_table">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>Is this an selected element?</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8zan1jyf/

As you can see, your CSS selector does address the `td` - or more specifically:

*any* `td` *within* a `tr` (that has the classname `'odd'`) *within* a `tbody` *within* a `table` (that has the classname `'exm_table'`)

There's probably no need to be quite that specific ;)

**UPDATE**

Since you've edited your question here's some further info about the alternating row style that seems to be confusing you.

`table.exm_table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td` uses the [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector to get tds in alternate rows.

`table.exm_table tbody tr.odd td` simply selects all tds within trs that have the classname 'odd'. (It's this classname that may be confusing because it has nothing to do with odd/even in itself and could just as easily be called 'bob')

Here's a demo to help clarify: http://jsfiddle.net/8zan1jyf/8/

```
/* to style ALL tds */
table.exm_table tbody tr td {background-color:pink;}
/* to style EVERY-OTHER td */
table.exm_table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td {background-color:red;}
/* to style td WHERE THE PARENT TR HAS THE CLASSNAME 'odd' (nothing to do with actual odd/even ordering) */
table.exm_table tbody tr.odd td {background-color:blue;}
/* to style td WHERE THE PARENT TR HAS THE CLASSNAME 'bob' */
table.exm_table tbody tr.bob td {background-color:green;}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I've made an error about tr. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

your initial css targets `td` and sets background to white (#fff)

---

you can just target classes directly

```
.exm_table {
    background-color:#ffffff;
}
.odd {
    background-color:#eeeeee;
}
```